# Output is not what I want C++

Tags: c++, fixed

I got some problems . I input a=5.999 with d=1 and expected output is 6 but its output is 6.0. I mean I want to delete **.0** in my output if it had.
Example: Input: 
a=3.864361,d=3,Output expected: 3.864/ Input:a=5.9577,d=1 Output expected: 6/ Input:
a=0.07266,d=3,Output expected:0.073.

```
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float a;
    int d;
    cin>>a>>d;
    cout<<setprecision(d)<<fixed<<a;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A minor detail, but why 5.999 should be 6 while 3.888 should be 3.88?

Comment: Interesting.. The documentation on cppreference, with examples, state that precision is how many digits, are generated. However, your testcase, and my experiments run on wandbox, show that precision controls the amount of digits, **after the decimal point**. And I am not sure who is correct.

Comment: So you've got 5.999 problems and d is 1

Comment: This is my mistake cauz my question is not clearly, With the example 5.888, I want 2 number after decimal point. But with 5.999, I want 1 number after decimal point and hope output is 6

Comment: https://wandbox.org/permlink/w1b5NsmWTIVSbe3Z

Comment: It runs on wandbox but , It doesn't run on CodeBlocks... yea ..

Comment: Note that meaning of precision changes depending if you are using `fixed` or `scientific` or `defaultfloat` https://wandbox.org/permlink/s2iSEvFZJVdPzIan and it must run on Code:Blocks

Comment: @MarekR I can't build it, Codeblocks says that " defaultfloat was not declare..." though I paste all your code in codeblocks

Comment: `defaultfloat` is available since `c++11`  you have to enable it (`-std=c++11`).

Answer (score -1):

Sadly, this is one example I know of where C++ solution is purely inferior to C. To the best of my knowledge, there is no way to do that with C++ streams.

On the other hand, C has `printf` format specifier exactly for that: [%g](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf)

Following code will do what you want (don't forget to include `stdio.h`):

```
printf("%.1g\n", a);
```

Comment: Well, my lecturer want me to use C++. Btw, thanks

Comment: @NgọcHuyền `printf` exists in both C and C++.

Comment: This works exactly as `std::defaultfloat` combined with `std::setprecision(1)`, so it's not better than C++ streams.